# Assigning data to the List from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I return some data from the controller using the `Ajax` call.

In the Notification area, I want to show this return data as a list using a loop.

Can you help me with this case?

This is my Nav area that I want to show the data as list

```
<ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu">
                                  
 </ul>
```

This is my return code

```
 function getData() {

   $('#menu1').empty();
   $('#menu1').append($('<li> Loading.. </li>'));
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: $("#Get").val(),
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {},
     success: function (data) {
       if (data.Success == true) {

         $('#menu1').empty();
         if (data.listNoti.length == 0) {
           $('')
           $('#menu1').append($('<li>There is nothing to show </li>'));
           console.log("No Data");
         }
         $("#notiCount").empty();
         $("#notiCount").append(data.listNoti.length);
         $.each(data.listNoti, function (index, value) {

           $("#menu1").append(value.Ndetails + '</br><hr />');

         });
       }
     }
   });
 }
```

Under that `ul` I want to add this return data `value.Ndetails` value as

```
<li>
  <a>
    <span class="message">value.Ndetails</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Because this is a loop, I want to know how this is done from the javascript.

Thanks.

-------------Updating--------------

This is the code that I retrieve images from the controller

```
<img src="@Url.Action("RetriveProfileImage","Account", new { id = item.Id })" onerror="this.src='/Theme/production/images/Profilepic.png'" sizes="50" />
```

I want to add the same to this javascript result. I did this

```
$("#menu1").append('<li> <a><span class="image"><img src="/RetriveProfileImage/Account/?id="' + value.ReUsr + ' alt="Profile Image" onerror="this.src=/Theme/production/images/Profilepic.png"></span> <span>'+value.Ndetails +'</span> </a></li>'+'</br><hr />');
```

It won't return the image, not directing to the path from this, How I apply it to here?

Comment: 1. Test if $("#menu1").append works by debugging and inspecting Dom element. 2. Test if /RetriveProfileImage/Account/?id=[valid id] works by opening it in browser